# Copy-Paste for tag excerpts allowed?

Tags: support, tag-excerpts

I've just seen the tag-except for [accel-world](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accel-world). By chance, I noticed, that the text was more or less copied from the [wikipedia-article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accel_World).

Is this allowed? Wikipedia has a [Creative Commons BY-AT license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License), so you need to name the source in **all** excerpts. How should it be handled? Ignore it? Make better excerpts? Or just name the source?

Comment: It also would be nice, if reviewers check that before approving.

Answer (score 6):

Better not. It's always better to reword it with your own words. I've seen this before and usually copy-paste excerpts are frowned upon. See also:

- [Can we do anything against tag wikis copy-pasted from Wikipedia?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102314/176533)
- [Would it be OK to paste content from Wikipedia into a popular empty tag-wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79000/176533)

And so on... :)

Better to err on the safe side. Reword it, it's not that hard after all.