# What can we do to organize an effort on the part of well-informed users to responsibly improve tag wiki content?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, tag-excerpts

As some users might be aware of, we have a handful tag wiki content that may have been directly obtained from other sites without proper attribution. I'd like to remind users that this practice is frowned upon.

For those reviewing the tag wiki suggestions, **please keep an eye out for plagiarized content reject and suggestions or new entries that plagiarise content without attribution or are otherwise unhelpful**. If a user's edit suggestions keep getting rejected, eventually they'll be automatically blocked from editing.

For those creating the content, please take a look at [this meta answer](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/386/63) about some guidelines that you can follow when when creating and editing tag wiki content.

If you find any plagiarized content please feel free to edit them or post them [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/anime-and-manga) so others may address them when available.

I do realized with out ever growing library of tags that out community can't always filling all unsummarized tags and someone new to the site, without a solid knowledge of plagiarism rules might such the deficit, and attempts to rectify it in their own way.

What efforts can we make on behalf of our community to responsibly improve tag wiki content?