# Why was my tag info for TQQ approved but not for Kaguya-sama?

Tags: discussion, tags

3 approvals (The Quintessential Quintuplets, Kaguya-sama) :

1. https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/70128
2. https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/70129
3. https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/69888

1 reject (Kaguya-sama) :

1. https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/69887

Why?

It says

> This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something useful to this community specifically, and be sure to attribute the original author. See: How to reference material written by others.

But how come that doesn't apply to the TQQ above?

Comment: All though I can't speak for the rejection, I approved the others because they did not seem to be a verbatim copy from wikipedia. However refer to: [is copy pasting tag excerpts allowed?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372/copy-paste-for-tag-excerpts-allowed) & [Do not Copy wikipedia (or Others) into tags](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/do-not-copy-blocks-of-text-from-wikipedia-etc-into-tag-wikis-excerpts)

Comment: Then that's my mistake, and they should have been rejected instead.

Comment: @Dimitrimx Wait I misspoke. I don't believe they were verbatim. See again. I made some changes like the '(2017-2020)'. For both kaguya-sama and TQQ I made edits.

Answer (score 7):

I've rejected the other edits. As noted above in the comments do not copy verbatim.

Comment: Wait I misspoke. I don't believe they were verbatim. See again. I made some changes like the '(2017-2020)'. For both kaguya-sama and TQQ I made edits.